# Generate MHT from HTM file

Tags: c#, html, mhtml

I have a htm page in my disk (C:\pages\page1.htm).

This page link CSS and gif (C:\pages\img\img1.gif, c:\pages\css\css1.css).

How can I generate MHT file ?? Only using C# .NET managed.

Comment: What's the purpose, if I may ask? Although the MHT looks like a useful format (and the Opera browser is capable of rendering it correctly), I've never seen it used.

Answer (score 0):

MHT is basically a MIME file, which means it's structured very much like an e-mail. There are some global headers at the top (namely, the `Content-Type`, which also specifies the content boundary). Each file in the archive is separated by the content boundary, and has its own set of headers. See [a MHT representation of this page](http://so.piskvor.org/1649379/Generate_MHT_from_HTM_file.mht) - much of the content is self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need this? MHT is IE-only format of storing webpages.

However, if you will open one MHT, you will quickly get an idea how to create it by hands.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 includes Recording Steps and generate mht file.

I thinks mht file can have several use. I need generate mht file (one mht file), for create several htm files, css , jpg, wmv...

thanks

Comment: This is not an answer to the question!